# Loader active class not enabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to have a semantic ui modal show a loader for 3 seconds, then disappear. Adding and removing the class works fine, but the delay doesn't.

**Javascript:**

```
function login_click() {
    $("#ld").addClass("active").delay(3000).removeClass("active");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui small modal" style="font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Login
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="ui form">
            <form method="post" action=""  id="loginForm">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left labeled icon input">
                        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20">
                        <i class="user icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui left labeled icon input">
                        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="50">
                        <i class="lock icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
          <input class="ui blue submit button" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
    <div id="ld" class="ui inverted dimmer">
        <div class="ui text loader">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.delay()` is only for use with `animations` you will have to use `setTimeout()` to get the same effect or if you intend on using this functionality allot you could extend jQuery and add a `toggleClassDelay` method. [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/Tq5Cx/).

```
$.fn.extend({
    //switchClass parameter is to replicate toggleClass functionality. 
    toggleClassDelay: function (className, delay, switchClass)
    {
        this.toggleClass(className, switchClass);

        setTimeout($.proxy(function ()
        {
            this.toggleClass(className, switchClass);
        }, this), delay);
    }
});
```

Then for your current example you would simple do:

```
$('#ld').toggleClassDelay('active', 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the function like this.

```
function login_click() {
    $("#ld").addClass("active");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#ld").removeClass("active");
    },3000);
}
```